# What should be the response status code when data present in body is not found in DB

Tags: rest, api

The request sent to api is :

```
url: /users/{userid}respource/{resourceid}
method: POST
body: {SubResourceId: 6, Message: ''}
```

So it is a post api. It creates some mapping of user and resource and subresource.
In this case if user or resource is not found , then api returns 404. But what should be the status code if subresource(which is passed in Body) is not found in DB?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a 4** error, because it is a client error, they are referencing a non-existent subresource. If you look at the definitions of the HTTP status errors you see that for example 400 bad request means bad syntax, where the client should not try the same request again. However a 404 means not found, yet it might be available in the future so the request can be tried again at a later time.

In all cases there should be an informative message offering more detail if available. So in this case you should probably send a 404 and a message explaining that the subresource cannot be found. Basically you are passing on a 404 from a deeper level.

There is an arguement to be made that 'the resource' that you refer to in the URI was found, and that 404 is not perfect. However looking at the various status codes available in the [w3c Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) there does not seem to be a more appropriate one.

The other option I would consider is a 500, internal server error. You could argue that the server should expect a request with a valid subresourceid. Since the subresource does not exist, the server cannot further process the request. Again, as long as their is a clear error message this can work, but it feels like more of a stretch than the 404.

But most importably, make sure you are consistent when it comes to error handling in your API(s).

Answer (score -1):

Ideally the response code should be 200 with message saying that no sub-resource was found, it can also be "204 No Content".  you can read more about it at [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

It needs to be consistent with Response codes you have been using throughout the application.

Comment: I don't think the response code should be any success status code. As the subresource is expected to be child of resource (which we have mentioned in api doc). So if that subresource is wrong then it is not a valid request . So, i think response status should 404 or 400.